# It is a bug of php about define?

Tags: php

Writing:

```
define ("MYARR", array(
    'TITLE' => "MY TITLE",
) );
```

And giving:

```
print_r(MYARR);
```

No error is returned. It is all ok! I display:

```
Array
(
   [TITLE] => MY TITLE
)
```

But if i write:

```
define ("MYARR['TITLE']", "MY TITLE");
```

I don't get a error, but giving:

```
print_r(MYARR);
```

I get:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant MYARR - assumed 'MYARR'
```

And giving:

```
echo MYARR['TITLE'];
```

I get this two warning:

```
1) Warning: Use of undefined constant MYARR
2) Warning: Illegal string offset 'TITLE'
```

About first warning, it not is correct, becouse as is possible to see above it is declared!
I think which is a bug of PHP. From a side is allowed declare constant of array but of other side not allowed. What is your opinion?

Comment: `"MYARR['TITLE']"` is a __string__. I hope you understand difference between string and array.

Comment: Not a bug in PHP at all, just a “bug” in _your_ understanding of what constants actually are and how they work.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php: _“Note: It is possible to define() constants with reserved or even invalid names, whose value can (only) be retrieved with constant(). However, doing so is not recommended.”_ - `var_dump(constant("MYARR['TITLE']"));` would get you your `MY TITLE` value here again. You can however not use `MYARR['TITLE']` as a constant _directly_ anywhere, because that kind of name would clash with the rest of the PHP syntax.

Comment: You can not create a “constant array” (if that’s what you’re attempting to do here) by doing `define ("MYARR['TITLE']", "MY TITLE"); define ("MYARR['FOO']", "BAR");` or anything like that - these would be _two_ separate constants, one with the name `MYARR['TITLE']` and one with the name `MYARR['FOO']`.

Comment: I know difference from string and array of course, but for me was a surprise which php not return a error when declare something as MYARR['TITLE'] which not can to be processed. Just for this reason, i talked about a possible bug.  But ok. Me just waited an error on it.